# How do I feed data into my web-service for a Windows 8 App?

Tags: mysql, web-services, windows-8

I'm learning how to develop Windows 8 Apps and I've just learned about web-services for the first time using the following tutorial:

[Tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)

Firstly, please accept my apologies if some of my terminology in inaccurate - hopefully you can still get the meaning!

I am using PhP, CSS, JavaScript or the app and MySQL for the database, I am for now developing locally.

I have managed to breakdown the web-service example and get it working with my local database, however in the example I am just entering a URL with parameters attached to the end directly into the web-browser, it is not being generated from anywhere.

How do I now progress to the next step and generate queries directly from my Windows 8 app that will query my database and then be processed by the Web Service?

I have discovered that Visual Studio has han included object that can interpret the results of the web service, however I don't know how to make a call to the database.

Thanks in advance for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call your web service from windows 8 app, using JS, you can use,

```
WinJS.xhr( {
url:'http://yourwebserviceurl'
}).then(function (response) {
   //response will be the response from your webservice,
})
```

After you get the response, you can process it to your windows 8 app, either your webservice using XML / JSON based.

If you prefer using jQuery, you can use jquery to request to your web service using this syntax

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your webservice url",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  //done
});
```

Cheers
Yusak Setiawan
http://apptivate.ms/apps/1271/mathboard

Comment: Thank you for your response, that helps a little bit, but I'm not quite sure I fully understand what the does despite having read the documentation on MSDN. I can't work out how to use responseXML to actually output the XML returned from WinJS.xhr